# Java: Proper Way of Making Directories

Tags: java, directory, createfile

Directories some_folder, some_folder_1, some_folder_2, and some_folder_3 don't exist initially.

```
File folder1 = new File("some_folder/some_folder_1"); 
File folder2 = new File("some_folder/some_folder_2"); 
File folder3 = new File("some_folder/some_folder_3"); 

if(!folder1.exists()) {
    folder1.mkdirs();
}

if(!folder2.exists()) {
    folder2.mkdirs();
}

if(!folder3.exists()) {
    folder3.mkdirs();
}
```

Would that be a good way to do this?

Comment: You may also want to check the return value of mkdirs() to ensure that the directory has been created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use the path separator, use the correct constructor instead:

```
File folder1 = new File("some_folder", "some_folder_1"); 
if (!folder1.exists()) {
    folder1.mkdirs(); // returns a boolean
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Well you don't need the tests - mkdirs just returns `false` if the directory already exists. I'd prefer to use one "base" file for `some_folder` to avoid hard-coding the slash, even though a forward slash is *likely* to work on most popular platforms :)

```
File baseFolder = new File("some_folder");
new File(baseFolder, "some_folder_1").mkdirs();
new File(baseFolder, "some_folder_2").mkdirs();
new File(baseFolder, "some_folder_3").mkdirs();
```

Note that this won't throw any exceptions if the names already exist but as *files* instead of folders...

Comment: To add to this, if you have more than 2 or 3 folders, you might want to consider loops and collections

Comment: Agreed (as per Carl's answer - except preferably with braces :)

Answer (score 1):

or

```
String[] folders = {"some_folder_1", "some_folder_2", "some_folder_3"};
File root = new File("some_folder");
for (String folder: folders)
    new File(root, folder).mkdirs();
```